# Magento 2: System Configuration not Reflecting

Tags: magento2, xml, system.xml, system-config

I creat system configurations in custom module. I am unable to get required changes in `store->configurations`.

The code I wrote for system.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="zipcodevalidator" translate="label" sortOrder="1">
        <label>Zipcode Validator</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="validatorsettings" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Validator Settings</label>
        <tab>zipcodevalidator</tab>
        <resource>Tm_Zipcode::config</resource>
        <group id="general_settings">
            <label>General Settings</label>
            <field id="enable_disable" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enable</label>
                <!-- <sorurce_model>Tm\Zipcode\Model\Yesno</source_model> -->
            </field>
            <field id="sucess_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Sucess Message</label>
                <comment>Use {zipcode} as zipcode placeholder and {days} as number of days placeholder</comment>
            </field>
            <field id="error_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Error Message</label>
                <comment>Use {zipcode} as zipcode placeholder</comment>
            </field>
    </section>
</system>
</config>
```

The code for acl.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                    <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                        <resource id="Tm_Zipcode::config_zipcode" title="Zipcode Section" sortOrder="50" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

I'm really stuck with this. Please help.

Comment: you mean to say, It not display in store configuration?

Comment: yes.....It won't display the changes.......only the default settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did this change in your code.

1. Change your resource that specify in acl.xml.
2. You need to add `</group>` in your above code.

replace your code with this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="zipcodevalidator" translate="label" sortOrder="1">
        <label>Zipcode Validator</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="validatorsettings" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Validator Settings</label>
        <tab>zipcodevalidator</tab>
        <resource>Tm_Zipcode::config_zipcode</resource>
        <group id="general_settings">
            <label>General Settings</label>
            <field id="enable_disable" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enable</label>
                <!-- <sorurce_model>Tm\Zipcode\Model\Yesno</source_model> -->
            </field>
            <field id="sucess_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Sucess Message</label>
                <comment>Use {zipcode} as zipcode placeholder and {days} as number of days placeholder</comment>
            </field>
            <field id="error_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Error Message</label>
                <comment>Use {zipcode} as zipcode placeholder</comment>
            </field>
      </group>
    </section>
</system>
</config>
```

Comment: no use.......I'm not getting any results

Comment: just remove var/ and try. we are using this code.

Comment: Do I need to have any other files except these files and module.xml

Comment: No, Can you share path of system.xml and acl.xml.

Comment: app/code/Tm/Zipcode/etc/adminhtml/system.xml & app/code/Tm/Zipcode/etc/acl.xml

Comment: You were right but I did some more mistakes........I changed the acl.xml location to app/code/Tm/Zipcode/etc/adminhtml/acl.xml and also changed <group id="general_settings"> to <group id="general" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

Answer (score 2):

you made a mistake in `resource` tab.

In you ACl configuration the resource id is **Tm_Zipcode::config_zipcode** .

So you have to use the same in the system.xml like

```
<resource>Tm_Zipcode::config_zipcode</resource>
```